# C# FTP Request stream locks up thread

Tags: ftp, stream, request

I am creating a C# app for transferring files over FTP. The code has worked flawlessly on 5 different systems all with decent internet access but I now have a 6th system that is having a problem closing the FTPRequest stream. This system is in a remote area of the country and only gets about 10 KBps transfer speeds. I do not know if the transfer speed has anything to do with the issue.

Here is my code.

```
string path = "ftp://ftp.myftpsite.com/SomeDirectory/SomeFile.avi";

FtpWebRequest reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(path));

reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(tbUsername.Text, tbPassword.Text);
reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;

reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
reqFTP.ContentLength = buffer.Length;

using (Stream strm = reqFTP.GetRequestStream())
{
   for (long l = 0; l < buffer.Length; l += 1024)
   {
      if (buffer.Length >= l + 1024)
      {
         strm.Write(buffer, (int)l, 1024);
      }
      else
      {
         int RemainingBytes = (int)(buffer.Length - l);
         strm.Write(buffer, (int)l, RemainingBytes);
      }
   }
}//Code gets stuck exiting the using statement
```

I tried without the using statement and closing the stream with .Close() and it also gets stuck there.

I have been searching possible solutions and work arounds for 3 days and have not been able to figure this one out. FYI, this code is run in a separate thread than my main program and it only fails on 1 out of 6 systems.